# HTML does not show decoded %3C?

Tags: javascript, html, decodeuricomponent

Following blocks of code are similar but have different input strings and hence different results:

```js
// This does not change HTML
var str = "%3Cdiv%3E"; // <div>
var str_dec = decodeURIComponent(str);
console.log(str_dec); // Console output is `<div>`
document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = "1: " + str_dec; // No HTML output

// This works fine within HTML
var str = "%3C0%3E"; // <0>
var str_dec = decodeURIComponent(str);
console.log(str_dec); // Console output is `<0>`
document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = "2: " + str_dec; // HTML output is `<0>`
```

```html
<p id="p1"></p>
<p id="p2"></p>
```

Although, console shows that decoding works fine in first case, why it does not  appear in the HTML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `<0>` is not a valid HTML tag, as SGML (the language which HTML used to be derived from) tags cannot begin with a digit:

> The element name immediately follows the tag open delimiter. An element name consist of a letter followed by up to 72 letters, digits, periods, or hyphens. Names are not case sensitive.

https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/HTMLandSGML.html

Since the code is assigning the [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) property of an `Element`, the browser tries to parse the value as HTML and isn't treating `<0>` as an HTML element, instead opting to treat it as a text value; whereas `<div>` is a valid HTML element, so the browser treats it as such.

If you inspect the output in the console, you'll actually see an empty `<div>` DOM node inside the paragraph `p1` (and the string `<0>` in `p2`):

[image]

If you don't want the browser to parse the assigned value as HTML, use the safer, simpler [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) property instead.

Answer (score 0):

> Although, console shows that decoding works fine in first case, why it
>   does not appear in the HTML?

A `<div>` element is within resulting `.innerHTML` of `<p>` element.

`"<div>"` creates `<div></div>` within resulting `html`.

Comment: Correct, but a bit on the simplistic side. Maybe you could expand it a bit?

Comment: @Kroltan Not sure what you mean? The `<div>` element does appear within `html` of `<p>` element. From perspective here, OP is not attempting to create `<0>` element, but rather, did not inspect `.innerHTML` of `<p>` element following process where `<div></div>` would be present as child node of `<p>`.

Comment: My comment was about the first version you posted, which was a single line ""<div>" creates <div></div> within resulting html."

Comment: @Kroltan Yes, that is correct, and adequate; no? Included reference to `.innerHTML` as the method which performs the action in `DOM` to render result.

Comment: Currently it is perfectly adequate, yes. (FYI, I didn't downvote)

Comment: @Kroltan No worries. Was in process of editing Answer to include reference to `.innerHTML` for completeness, concurrent with your comment.